# Consulta a la BD con WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy haciendo una consulta para que me saque los datos de dos tablas relacionadas.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT vi.vivienda_id, vi.localidad, vi.ciudad, vi.nombre, vi.foto, vi.estado_id, vi.etiqueta_id, vi.precio, vi.metros, vi.habitaciones, vi.descripcion, et.etiqueta_id, et.etiqueta AS nombreETQ
FROM vivienda AS vi, etiqueta AS et
WHERE vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id");
  foreach ($results as $res):
    $precio = $res['precio'];
    $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];
    $nombreETQ = $res['nombreETQ'];
```

Esto esta bien, pero lo que hace es decir que saque las que hay iguales `vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id`, pero claro puede ser que una se `NULL`pero necesito que la saque.

Realmente lo que hago tengo una tabla que se llama `vivienda` otra `etiqueta`, en vivienda guardo un numero en `etiqueta_id` que pertenece al etiqueta_id de la tabla etiqueta. Así de ese modo saco el nombre no el numero. Espero explicarme bien...

Comment: Si necesitas obtener los datos, y que estos incluya nulos, averigua sobre `LEFT|RIGHT JOIN` =)

Comment: Gracias ya lo solucione, no recordaba esto :) @PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Con un **LEFT JOIN**

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT vi.vivienda_id, vi.localidad, vi.ciudad, vi.nombre, vi.foto, vi.estado_id, vi.etiqueta_id, vi.precio, vi.metros, vi.habitaciones, vi.descripcion, et.etiqueta_id, et.etiqueta AS nombreETQ
  FROM vivienda AS vi
  LEFT JOIN  etiqueta AS et ON vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id");
   foreach ($results as $res):
    $precio = $res['precio'];
    $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];
    $nombreETQ = $res['nombreETQ'];
```